# SQL Script for SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-scripts

I'm developing an app that uses SQL Azure. I don't have an account to access Windows Azure and I want to start writing SQL script.

Can I use my SQL Server 2008 to test my SQL Azure script?

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend a SQL Azure account.  However, if you dont have access to one, you can create the DB in SQL 2008, then export a SQL Azure compatable script.  Then use that script for testing purposes.

Here is a link:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2010/06/04/importing-exporting-data-to-sql-azure-databases-using-bcp-and-sql-scripts.aspx

One thing you should accomodate for when coding for SQL Azure is a failover or retry policy per this article:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/11/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling.aspx#comments

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because certain SQL statements are not supported, or partially supported. So unless you are already very familiar with the differences between SQL Azure and SQL Server the general recommendation is to create your scripts against a SQL Azure database.

Opening an Account is really simple. Remember that when you create a SQL Azure database your charges are pro-rated daily. So if you create a development database of 1GB is size (the minimum) you will pay $9.99 per month (plus a really low transfer cost), or "roughly" 33 cents per day. If you create a 1GB database on a Monday and drop it the following Wednesday, you will pay roughly a buck. There are no charges for the master database.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Herve.  It would likely be best if you actually use SQL Azure as there are some differences between SQL Sever and SQL Azure.  You can get a free 30 day account (with no credit card) using the following:

Use this link: http://www.windowsazurepass.com/?campid=9FE3DB53-E4F0-DF11-B2EA-001F29C6FB82
Use this passcode: promo code = DPEWE01

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And which country may I use? I think that promo code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is actually the right way, you can create a database in you local SQL Server 2008 instance, I would recommend using latest community edition for this purpose.

Create database, tables.. work on it, then generate a script to later export to SQL Azure.

Make sure to see documentation for pressing changes or things not to use while doing your job that might not be working on SQL Azure.